# Best way to initialize objects which can be used by all junit test cases

Tags: java, junit

I'm not sure if a question similar to this already exists but i was not able to find any helpful answers.

I have to create a list of objects that are supposed to be used by all the junit test cases.

If i write a `@BeforeClass` method like this:

```
 @BeforeClass
 static public void setUp() {
    MyObject object = new MyObject (int a, Stringb)
 }
```

It does n't work because these objects are out of scope for the junit test cases

And if i write `@BeforeClass` method like this:

```
Class Abc{
    MyObject object; 
    @BeforeClass
     static public void setUp() {
        object = new MyObject (int a, Stringb)
     }
}
```

There's a compilation error as i can't access non static variable from static class.

I could make all the objects static but that seems unnecessary to me. 
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: So, don't use BeforeClass, but use Before

Comment: Instantiating your objects for each test execution is fine so a simple `@Before` is okay here. Getting a new instance of test objects is good practice as some test cases may mutate / change these objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using `@Before` for your use case:

```
class Abc {

    MyObject object; 

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        object = new MyObject();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // Use object
    }
}
```

Comment: I was refraining to use @Before because the initializations were same for all the classes and there was not going to be any change in the objects. So i thought it would be an overhead to initialize everything again for all the test cases.

Comment: It depends on how expensive the initialization is. If it is really time-consuming and you have 100+ tests, `@BeforeClass` is certainly preferrable. In that case `object` needs to be static variable. However, if you are simply creating a small test object for 10 tests, the difference is pretty much negligible.